# Force python to print entire number

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is my problem:

If I try for example to print the result of :

```
2**64
```

will print:

```
18446744073709551616L
```

But now if I want to print the result of :

```
1.8446744*10**19
```

This will print:

```
1.8446744e+19
```

So my question is : how can I print the entire result of 1.8446744e+19 I want to see :

```
18446744000000000000
```

And what means the sign L at the end of my numbers ?

Comment: How are you "printing" these? the `L` shouldn't be shown if you use `print`.

Comment: @Wooble If you just use the python terminal, and evaluate `2**64` it'll print out as OP states:
`>>> 2**64
18446744073709551616L
`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First the L at the end of your number means the type is a 'long' you can check the type by:

```
>>> type(18446744000000000000)
long
```

Then to get your result not as a scientific notation you can just convert your number to a long:

```
>>> long(1.8446744*10**19)
18446744000000000000L
```

You can try to convert it as an int, python will automatically convert it as a long.

PS : This works only for python 2.2 and upper but not for python 3

Comment: Just use `int` instead of `long` and it'll be fine up to a point anyway

Answer (score 10):

Use string formatting to set the format you want to display:

```
>>> print "%.0f" % (1.8446744*10**19)
18446744000000000000
```